# OpenCV Error with PCA

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, pca

I am new at Machine learning.

I am trying to build an ANN MLP for expression recognition;

But first I will use a PCA, but program crash with this error 
:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(_cols, _rows)) in cv::_OutputArray::create, file C:\buildslave64\win64_amdocl\master_PackSlave-win64-vc14-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 2232
```

First I read the images, they are 40 (48x48 gray scale images) and I get an `vector<Mat> images_train`, then I use the method transfVectorToMat that create a Mat where each row is an image.

```
Mat rawTrainData = transfVectortoMat(images_train);
```

pca_zise is the feactures that I want:
    `int pca_size = 1500;`

Here I create a Mat for the output of PCA:

```
Mat trainData(rawTrainData.rows, pca_size, rawTrainData.type());
```

Here I create the PCA:

```
PCA pca(rawTrainData, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, pca_size);
```

I get the error with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rawTrainData.rows; i++) {
    pca.project(rawTrainData.row(i), trainData.row(i));
}
```

any idea to solve this error?

I am using visual studio 2013

Comment: I said the error. first line of code

Comment: So you did, my mistake.